# I want to bulk download Images from a website using iframe but can't get the specific url

Tags: iframe

I hope this kind of question is ok to ask here.

So, I'm working on building a database to use as training in a neural network. For this, I want to bulk download some images from a nice Italian pottery website — however, this requires the website having a unique url, which is "hidden": The creator of the website used iframe, so I can't view the specific url. Any ideas on how to work around this?

The (non specific) link is https://bbcc.ibc.regione.emilia-romagna.it/pater/search.do.
Visit https://bbcc.ibc.regione.emilia-romagna.it/pater/search.do?type=&group=GROUP0&customquery=*%3A*+-TYPE%3An+&value%28ANY%29=boccale, then go to the next page. The url becomes non unique.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

right click the Iframe and check its src attribute. that's your url